# Behavior of QueryLocator in Batches

Tags: apex, batch

I have a batch job that reads records from a table and does some processing.  During the `execute` method, these records are deleted.

This job can, under certain circumstances, be running more than once. I am worried about an instance in which the records that Job #2 is trying to process have been deleted by Job #1.

The question is:

How does the `Database.QueryLocator` works? Will it attempt to retrieve (or somehow earmark) all the records during the `start` method or will a quick query be run before each `execute` method?

If it's the latter, I feel ok about my job. If it's the former, what do you suggest to avoid my scenario?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're speaking of a single batch job that queries less than 200 records? Otherwise, like triggers, any batch job runs in separate "chunks" of 200 records at a time. Those records can be locked if in use by another process, at which point contention & concurrency becomes an issue.

Comment: So, not quite. I am talking about hundreds of thousands of records. concurrency is not a problem in my case (it doesn't bother me that I might be processing the record twice) but contention is what I am concerned about.

The question is, will the queryMore potentially get records that have already been deleted?

Comment: Here's some additional info about the QueryLocator behavior that might inform the answer a bit: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/96871/660

Comment: @MarkPond Make that an answer so I can accept it.... That was the answer I needed.... though not the one I hoped for.

Comment: I fear its first one and I am hoping it does not show you ENTITY IS  DELETED error but again i am guessing and never came across this scenario .

Comment: @Mo, I agree, based on Mark's answer. I can code to account for that, so I think I'll be fine in the end.